Internal Error on Gemini Batch predictions in GCP
I am trying to follow the guide as provided here: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/multimodal/batch-prediction-gemini to do batch prediction on audio files. I have the following JSON structures:
{
   "contents":[
      {
         "role":"user",
         "parts":[
            {
               "text":"do xyz"
            },
            {
               "inline_data":{
                  "mime_type":"audio/wav",
                  "data":"<encoded data>"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "system_instruction":{
      "parts":[
         {
            "text":"long instruction"
         }
      ]
   },
   "generation_config":{
      "max_output_tokens":8192,
      "temperature":0.9,
      "top_p":0.95
   }
}

which I have already validated to work as intended with the Gemini api. As instructed in the guide, I have a BigQuery table with a column named Request of type JSON, with each JSON on it's own row, with approximately 30000 entries. Then, as Instructed, I start the Batch prediction via the API utilizing following source code:
import requests

url = "https://europe-west6-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myprivateproject/locations/europe-west6/batchPredictionJobs"
payload = {
    "name": "new-run",
    "displayName": "NewRun",
    "model": "publishers/google/models/gemini-1.5-pro-001",
    "inputConfig": {
        "instancesFormat": "bigquery",
        "bigquerySource": {
            "inputUri": "bq://myprivateproject.datasetname.GeminiBatchTable"
        }
    },
    "outputConfig": {
        "predictionsFormat": "bigquery",
        "bigqueryDestination": {
            "outputUri": "bq://myprivateproject.datasetname.GeminiBatchTable"
        }
    }
}

# Get the access token
access_token = get_access_token()

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
print(response.json())
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Request successful!")
    print("Response:", response.json())
else:
    print("Failed to send request:", response.status_code)
    print("Response:", response.text)

This starts a job on vertexai that stays on Pending and then crashes.

There is also no logging information. The only error provided is Error (INTERNAL), which is not helpful for debugging. I am unsure of what might be the cause but I assume that it's likely got to do with either:

This crashes due to access control because it is not in full general availability
I am supposed to create a table with the target structure
I am setting the target table location wrongly (I tried other configurations but the api complains that the table does not exist otherwise)

I would be grateful if anyone could maybe point out any obvious mistake that I may be making.

Hi @Giancarlo Metitieri, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

First, try to test with smaller batch size, i.e test with only ~10 (or smaller) requests (rows in bigquery). Your issue is likely running out of quota. Once you confirm that's the case, you can request quota increase through console or with your support team.

@GangChen, I ran into this same unspecified error with code 13 and message "INTERNAL" similar to OP and just yesterday, too. Can you point to docs on how quotas are set and work with batch predictions in GCP? My requests totaled under 100. Is there a time limit parameter to use? Any way to know more than "INTERNAL" like log files?

Can you try with a single batch request (1 prediction)? This will ensure that the batch processing configuration is correct. From there, increasing the batch size will tell whether you are hitting the quota / resource constraints. Keep in minds, this is a preview or pre-GA feature

Thanks @GangChen, I tried with 1 prediction and still job errors out with code 13 and message "INTERNAL". In a past attempt, audit logs showed an SQL syntax error to my BigQuery table (auto-generated and not by me) of a missing column in SELECT clause. Though in recent attempts including this sample of 1, audit logs show no severity error though curl request indicates job failed. So, I can't debug. I guess I'll wait until this batch predictions product matures. (FYI: OpenAI batch api in Python is seamless). I will just run long loops with google-generativeai.

@Parfait is it possible to share more detail of your job setup? including curl command with request payload, and bigquery structure. Your case is not quota related for sure. Also, are you using gemini-1.0-pro-001? If so, I suggest changing it to gemini-1.0-pro-002. It can further analyze the issue once you post the job detail.

@GangChen, see my new post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78613847/1422451. I just attempted gemini-1.0-pro-002 with same uninformative Error Code 13.

If you have VPC security controls enabled, it can cause the behavior you're seeing.
You can confirm by checking Logs Explorer for the time period when the job was active, and looking for VPC errors (for me, filtering by job ID did not display the VPC errors, instead I searched just using a time range).
If you do find VPC errors, here is Google's issue tracker for using Gemini batch API with VPC-SC enabled:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/354176501
