Running Gemini Batch Predictions via Curl Request Raises Error Code 13 - INTERNAL
Diligently following the Get batch predictions for Gemini instructions, I attempted the following curl request against a BigQuery dataset shown below. I have attempted multiple models (gemini-1.5-flash-001, gemini-1.5-pro-001, gemini-1.0-pro-002) that all raise the same uninformative Error Code 13 - INTERNAL.
Am I following the correct specifications, especially the BigQuery input and output URI sources? Is the model input with its parameters correctly specified?
Run
Curl Request (ran inside GCP cloud terminal shell)
curl -X POST \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
     -d @request.json \
     "https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/XXXXXXXXX/locations/us-central1/batchPredictionJobs"

Request JSON (ran literally inside above call in place of @request.json)
{
  "name": "economic_goods_batch",
  "displayName": "economic_goods_batch",
  "model": "publishers/google/models/gemini-1.5-flash-001",
  "inputConfig": {
    "instancesFormat": "bigquery",
    "bigquerySource": {
      "inputUri": "bq://XXXXXXXXX.gemini_econ_goods_batch.sample"
    }
  },
  "outputConfig": {
    "predictionsFormat": "bigquery",
    "bigqueryDestination": {
      "outputUri": "bq://XXXXXXXXX.gemini_econ_goods_batch.sample"
    }
  }
}

BigQuery Table: Sample
Contains one JSON type column, Request, with first row. I attempted to run on full table containing 99 rows and sample table containing 1 row. Both attemptes raised the Error code 13.
{
  "contents": [
    {
      "parts": "Which of the following types of economic goods describes the activity of playing baseball: public good, private good, common resources, and/or club good?. Please answer with a description.",
      "role": "user"
    }
  ],
  "generation_config": {
    "maxOutputTokens": 1000,
    "top_k": 5
  },
  "system_instruction": {
    "parts": [
      {
        "text": "You are an economics trained assistant. Your response must be a JSON array containing JSON objects of two elements: good_type and description."
      }
    ]
  }
}

Result
curl \
  -X GET \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/gen-lang-client-XXXXXXXXX/locations/us-central1/batchPredictionJobs

{
  "batchPredictionJobs": [
    {
      "name": "projects/????????????/locations/us-central1/batchPredictionJobs/????????????",
      "displayName": "economic_goods_batch",
      "model": "publishers/google/models/gemini-1.0-pro-002",
      "inputConfig": {
        "instancesFormat": "bigquery",
        "bigquerySource": {
          "inputUri": "bq://gen-lang-client-XXXXXXXXX.gemini_econ_goods_batch.economic_goods_batch"
        }
      },
      "outputConfig": {
        "predictionsFormat": "bigquery",
        "bigqueryDestination": {
          "outputUri": "bq://gen-lang-client-XXXXXXXXX.gemini_econ_goods_batch.economic_goods_batch"
        }
      },
      "state": "JOB_STATE_FAILED",
      "error": {
        "code": 13,
        "message": "INTERNAL"
      },
      "createTime": "2024-06-12T15:40:31.753722Z",
      "startTime": "2024-06-12T15:40:31.962421Z",
      "endTime": "2024-06-12T15:42:50.600106Z",
      "updateTime": "2024-06-12T15:42:50.600106Z",
      "modelVersionId": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "projects/????????????/locations/us-central1/batchPredictionJobs/????????????",
      "displayName": "economic_goods_batch",
      "model": "publishers/google/models/gemini-1.5-flash-001",
      "inputConfig": {
        "instancesFormat": "bigquery",
        "bigquerySource": {
          "inputUri": "bq://gen-lang-client-XXXXXXXXX.gemini_econ_goods_batch.sample"
        }
      },
      "outputConfig": {
        "predictionsFormat": "bigquery",
        "bigqueryDestination": {
          "outputUri": "bq://gen-lang-client-XXXXXXXXX.gemini_econ_goods_batch.sample"
        }
      },
      "state": "JOB_STATE_FAILED",
      "error": {
        "code": 13,
        "message": "INTERNAL"
      },
      "createTime": "2024-06-11T20:07:10.340485Z",
      "startTime": "2024-06-11T20:07:10.522629Z",
      "endTime": "2024-06-11T20:08:59.225966Z",
      "updateTime": "2024-06-11T20:08:59.225966Z",
      "modelVersionId": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "projects/????????????/locations/us-central1/batchPredictionJobs/????????????",
      "displayName": "economic_goods_batch",
      "model": "publishers/google/models/gemini-1.5-flash-001",
      "inputConfig": {
        "instancesFormat": "bigquery",
        "bigquerySource": {
          "inputUri": "bq://gen-lang-client-XXXXXXXXX.gemini_econ_goods_batch.economic_goods_batch"
        }
      },
      "outputConfig": {
        "predictionsFormat": "bigquery",
        "bigqueryDestination": {
          "outputUri": "bq://gen-lang-client-XXXXXXXXX.gemini_econ_goods_batch.economic_goods_batch"
        }
      },
      "state": "JOB_STATE_FAILED",
      "error": {
        "code": 13,
        "message": "INTERNAL"
      },
      "createTime": "2024-06-10T22:44:19.973904Z",
      "startTime": "2024-06-10T22:44:20.180562Z",
      "endTime": "2024-06-10T22:46:38.819981Z",
      "updateTime": "2024-06-10T22:46:38.819981Z",
      "modelVersionId": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "projects/????????????/locations/us-central1/batchPredictionJobs/????????????",
      "displayName": "economic_goods_batch",
      "model": "publishers/google/models/gemini-1.5-pro-001",
      "inputConfig": {
        "instancesFormat": "bigquery",
        "bigquerySource": {
          "inputUri": "bq://gen-lang-client-XXXXXXXXX.gemini_econ_goods_batch.economic_goods_batch"
        }
      },
      "outputConfig": {
        "predictionsFormat": "bigquery",
        "bigqueryDestination": {
          "outputUri": "bq://gen-lang-client-XXXXXXXXX.gemini_econ_goods_batch.economic_goods_response"
        }
      },
      "state": "JOB_STATE_FAILED",
      "error": {
        "code": 13,
        "message": "INTERNAL"
      },
      "createTime": "2024-06-09T18:26:52.102913Z",
      "startTime": "2024-06-09T18:26:52.299451Z",
      "endTime": "2024-06-09T18:28:40.856695Z",
      "updateTime": "2024-06-09T18:28:40.856695Z",
      "modelVersionId": "1"
    }
  ]
}

GCP audit logs show strange syntax errors at datetimes that do not correspond to job request. Such logs are not immediately available after job request.
[
After correcting the BigQuery input data, the same Error Code 13 persisted. And few minutes later, the below severity error shows in logs. Why is an incorrect SQL syntax query being auto-generated with a LIMIT clause?
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 11,
      "message": "Syntax error: SELECT list must not be empty at [1:9]"
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "???????????????@gmail.com"
    },
    "requestMetadata": {
      "callerIp": "??.???.??.???",
      "callerSuppliedUserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)",
      "requestAttributes": {},
      "destinationAttributes": {}
    },
    "serviceName": "bigquery.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "jobservice.insert",
    "authorizationInfo": [
      {
        "resource": "projects/gen-lang-client-XXXXXXXXX",
        "permission": "bigquery.jobs.create",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {}
      }
    ],
    "resourceName": "projects/gen-lang-client-XXXXXXXXX/jobs",
    "serviceData": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.bigquery.logging.v1.AuditData",
      "jobInsertRequest": {
        "resource": {
          "jobName": {
            "projectId": "gen-lang-client-XXXXXXXXX"
          },
          "jobConfiguration": {
            "query": {
              "query": "SELECT  FROM `gen-lang-client-XXXXXXXXX.gemini_econ_goods_batch.economic_goods_batch` LIMIT 1000",
              "destinationTable": {},
              "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
              "writeDisposition": "WRITE_EMPTY",
              "defaultDataset": {},
              "queryPriority": "QUERY_INTERACTIVE"
            },
            "dryRun": true
          }
        }
      },
      "jobInsertResponse": {
        "resource": {
          "jobName": {},
          "jobConfiguration": {},
          "jobStatus": {
            "state": "PENDING",
            "error": {}
          },
          "jobStatistics": {
            "reservation": "unreserved"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "insertId": "????????????",
  "resource": {
    "type": "bigquery_resource",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "gen-lang-client-XXXXXXXXX"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2024-06-13T16:14:22.731549Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/gen-lang-client-XXXXXXXXX/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2024-06-13T16:14:23.236589188Z"
}


Before running above batch predictions attempt, I have tested a single call with the Gemini Python API against same models to successfully receive output.
import os
import google.generativeai as genai

genai.configure(api_key=os.environ["GEMINIAI_API_KEY"])

model = genai.GenerativeModel(
    model_name = model_name = "gemini-1.5-flash-001", # "gemini-1.5-pro-001", #"gemini-1.5-pro-latest",
    system_instruction = (
        "You are an economics trained assistant. "
        "Your response must be a JSON array containing a list of "
        "JSON objects of two elements: good_type and description."
    )
)

prompt = (
    "Which of the following types of economic goods describes "
    "the activity of playing baseball: public good, "
    "private good, common resources, and/or club good?. "
    "Please answer with a description."
)


response = model.generate_content(
    prompt,
    generation_config=genai.GenerationConfig(
        response_mime_type = "application/json",
        max_output_tokens = 1000,
        top_k = 5
    )
)

print(response.text)

[
   {
      "good_type":"club good",
      "description":"A club good is a good that is excludable but not rivalrous. Playing baseball can be considered a club good because it is possible to exclude people from playing (e.g., requiring membership in a league or payment for access to a field). However, the enjoyment of the game by one person does not diminish the enjoyment of others. It is possible to have multiple players on the field at the same time without decreasing the enjoyment of the game for anyone."
   },
   {
      "good_type":"common resource",
      "description":"A common resource is a good that is rivalrous but not excludable.  This means that it is possible for multiple people to use the resource, but the resource is limited. Playing baseball can be considered a common resource because it can be rivalrous depending on the situation. For example, if there is only one baseball field available, then the enjoyment of the game by one group of people may diminish the enjoyment of the game for another group of people. However, it may be difficult to exclude people from playing baseball, especially if the game is played in a public park."
   }
]

Do note, attempting model, gemini-1.0-pro-002, raised:

google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 models/gemini-1.0-pro-002 is not found for API version v1beta, or is not supported for GenerateContent. Call ListModels to see the list of available models and their supported methods.


are you sure your running in us-central1,  python would pick it up from the env var but your hard coding it in curl. where is your cloud instance setup?  Also i tested with  gemini-1.5-flash-001 and not gemini-1.5-pro-001

I noticed one issue with your bigQuery input data, please update with following:
{
  "contents": [
    {
      "parts": {
          "text": "Which of the following types of economic goods describes the activity of playing baseball: public good, private good, common resources, and/or club good?. Please answer with a description."
      },
      "role": "user"
    }
  ],
  "generation_config": {
    "maxOutputTokens": 1000,
    "top_k": 5
  },
  "system_instruction": {
    "parts": [
      {
        "text": "You are an economics trained assistant. Your response must be a JSON array containing JSON objects of two elements: good_type and description."
      }
    ]
  }
}

parts should an object with text field.
Try that fix with publishers/google/models/gemini-1.5-flash-001.
gemini-1.0-pro-002 should work for Vertex AI endpoint, I guess yours is with Google AI Studio.

I agree with the parts but they say that it works with python but not with curl which means if python can process the same bq table it should work fine in curl.

The Python code uses non-batch sync API generate_content, which is a different API than the batchPrediction used in curl though the underneath foundation model is the same.

Great catch, @GangChen. However, after correcting the input data, the job hung a little in queue but still ended with Error 13. And a few minutes later, I found a severity error in audit logs which I edited above post. See below error screenshot. API appears to auto-generate an incorrect SQL statement.

hmm, just to troubleshoot the issue, can you try: 1. Limit the batch size to just 1 (1 row in biquery table). 2. change the bigquery dataset.table to bq://gen-lang-client-XXXXXXXXX.gemini.batchsample (need to create bq dataset and table)

Months later @GangChen, I retried a new batch and a one-row BQ table sample which both returned the unspecified Error 13. Under status of error in Logs Explorer, an SQL issue shows: Syntax error: SELECT list must not be empty at [1:9]. Is BigQuery running invalid SQL? Can you reproduce my issue on a personal machine not affiliated with Google?

If you have VPC security controls enabled, it can cause the behavior you're seeing.
You can confirm by checking Logs Explorer for the time period when the job was active, and looking for VPC errors (for me, filtering by job ID did not display the VPC errors, instead I searched just using a time range).
If you do find VPC errors, here is Google's issue tracker for using Gemini batch API with VPC-SC enabled:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/354176501

Just ran a new batch with same Error 13 in curl output but does not yet show up in Logs Explorer. Do these VPC errors show under the error severity (red exclamation icon) or as info or notices? And did you ever resolve such errors? Cited external link does not immediately show resolution. Otherwise, your post should be a comment and not answer.

After several trials across months, the BigQuery input format did not work for me. Regardless of number of rows, each attempt still raised the strange SQL syntax "Syntax error: SELECT list must not be empty at [1:9]" which appears to be outside of user's control.
Interestingly (and maybe relatedly), this error is also thrown inside the BigQuery console when you click Query on an open table, serving as a red-colored reminder to users to enter field(s). Possibly the Batch Job API via BigQuery input runs this incomplete SQL query as default. But since a request column is required for BigQuery inputs per above docs, why not default to SELECT request FROM ...?

However, the Cloud Storage input format worked for my use case and very fast! Simply, point the input to your .jsonl of requests located in your bucket and a new or existing .jsonl in same bucket for the output. Below shows structure of my payload and example of one returned response:
payload (embedded in curl request)
{
   "displayName":"my-request-batch",
   "model":"publishers/google/models/gemini-1.5-pro-001",
   "inputConfig":{
      "instancesFormat":"jsonl",
      "gcsSource":{
         "uris":"gs://my-bucket/request_input.jsonl"
      }
   },
   "outputConfig":{
      "predictionsFormat":"jsonl",
      "gcsDestination":{
         "outputUriPrefix":"gs://my-bucket/response_output.jsonl"
      }
   }
}

response (text objects truncated)
{
   "status":"",
   "processed_time":"2024-11-04T01:14:12.777+00:00",
   "request":{
      "contents":[
         {
            "parts":{
               "text":"Please list ..."
            },
            "role":"user"
         }
      ],
      "generation_config":{
         "max_output_tokens":1000,
         "top_k":5
      },
      "system_instruction":{
         "parts":[
            {
               "text":"You are an expert in ..."
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "response":{
      "candidates":[
         {
            "avgLogprobs":-0.08164145350456238,
            "content":{
               "parts":[
                  {
                     "text":"Response is..."
                  }
               ],
               "role":"model"
            },
            "finishReason":"STOP",
            "safetyRatings":[
               {
                  "category":"HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH",
                  "probability":"NEGLIGIBLE",
                  "probabilityScore":0.19433594,
                  "severity":"HARM_SEVERITY_NEGLIGIBLE",
                  "severityScore":0.10986328
               },
               {
                  "category":"HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT",
                  "probability":"NEGLIGIBLE",
                  "probabilityScore":0.21289063,
                  "severity":"HARM_SEVERITY_LOW",
                  "severityScore":0.22558594
               },
               {
                  "category":"HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT",
                  "probability":"NEGLIGIBLE",
                  "probabilityScore":0.18554688,
                  "severity":"HARM_SEVERITY_NEGLIGIBLE",
                  "severityScore":0.11279297
               },
               {
                  "category":"HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT",
                  "probability":"NEGLIGIBLE",
                  "probabilityScore":0.10839844,
                  "severity":"HARM_SEVERITY_NEGLIGIBLE",
                  "severityScore":0.08886719
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "modelVersion":"gemini-1.5-pro-001@default",
      "usageMetadata":{
         "candidatesTokenCount":5,
         "promptTokenCount":154,
         "totalTokenCount":159
      }
   }
}

